# I want to use a regular class library on XBox360!

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360

why can't I use regular class libraries in XBox360 games?

I have application logic which I want to keep independent from XNA and use in both WPF and XNA applications.

Does anyone know good practice to share code between XBox/Phone7 applications and "regular" windows applications?

Comment: Using XNA Game Studio, I was able to share my library projects between PC, XBox360 and WP7 without issues. The only trick is using the library *projects* inside your game project, not the DLLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Portable Class Libraries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

> Using the Portable Class Library
>   project, you can build portable
>   assemblies that work without
>   modification on the .NET Framework,
>   Silverlight, Windows Phone 7, or XNA
>   (Xbox) platforms. Without the Portable
>   Class Library project, you must target
>   a single platform and then manually
>   rework the class library for other
>   platforms. The Portable Class Library
>   project supports a subset of
>   assemblies from these platforms, and
>   provides a Visual Studio template that
>   makes it possible to build assemblies
>   that run without modification on these
>   platforms.

Comment: Sounds like a better solution than mine - I didn't realise this existed! Looks like there are some restrictions on these types of projects, but if you can use it, it's a much nicer way.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution! I am currently moving everything to portable libraries - unfortunately, my serialization isn't supported anymore. Any experience which serialization method I should use? XML serialization?

Comment: If something isn't support in the Portable Class Libraries, you could try a combination of the mirrored XNA projects (as described in Andrew Russel's answer) and Linked Files into the Silverlight project (my answer)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Check out [JoDG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830120/i-want-to-use-a-regular-class-library-on-xbox360/5830520#5830520) for a nicer solution.

You could try linked files...

In your Xbox project, right-click -> Add Existing File, then after selecting the file(s), click the little drop-down arrow on the "Add" button and click "Add As Link", as shown here:

[image: Add As Link]

This might not work if you need to share more than just files, but it's an easy way to share code.

Answer (score 1):

JoDG's answer is probably the most practically useful. But just to provide additional information:

> why can't I use regular class libraries in XBox360 games?

Because the different XNA platforms target different versions of the .NET framework.

XNA Game Studio itself provides a mechanism ([documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282466.aspx) and [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976061.aspx)) for automatically mirroring the source files of a project between two projects. This mechanism can be used for creating copies of your library projects for each platform, as well as for your game projects.

For XNA-related work, this is the preferred method for creating cross-platform libraries. When you have to also make your library work on WPF you have to take additional steps:

On Windows, an XNA game is just like any other .NET application, and a XNA library for Windows is just like any other .NET library. **Except** for the fact that they reference XNA assemblies. So your WPF application can reference a Windows version of your XNA library. But if you want your application to work on systems without XNA installed, you need to *remove* the XNA assembly references from the Windows project for that XNA library.

XNA Game Studio will still mirror changes between the Windows library and the Xbox 360 library for you.